# Custom CIKernel and iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I have an iOS project that supports devices running both iOS 7 and 8 (project deployment target: 7.0) and I have recently started implementing a custom CIKernel with the new API introduced in iOS 8.

While the code compiles and runs with no issues in every iOS 8 device, every time I try to run it in an iOS 7 device I get this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CIColorKernel
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/...
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
 in /var/mobile/Applications/...
```

The code that generates the error is this one:

```
kernel = [CIColorKernel kernelWithString:kernelStr];
```

The `kernelWithString:` method was introduced in iOS8, as the CIKernel.h declares:

```
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10, __IPHONE_8_0);
```

So my question is: How can I make the app run on both iOS 7 and 8 devices and just have my custom CIKernel feature disabled for the iOS 7 devices? Is that possible?

Note that I have changed the CoreImage.framework from 'Required' to 'Optional' from the project settings and the app runs in iOS7.0 devices but it feels really hack-y to be honest.

I have also tried the preprocessor commands: `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` and `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` but those are useful only for compile time.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Class colorKernelClass = NSClassFromString(@"CIColorKernel");
kernel = [colorKernelClass kernelWithString:str];
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: How can I make the app run on both iOS 7 and 8 devices and just have my custom CIKernel feature disabled for the iOS 7 devices? Is that possible?

You can check the version of the OS at runtime like this:

```
NSString *osVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

This gives a string that you can parse and extract the major version...

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well but the error keeps showing up.